# Django Test Wants Access To Master Database MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, django, django-testing, django-tests

I've got an application that is running Django 2 that connects to a Microsoft SQL Server backend.

We're in a big environment where things are pretty tightly controlled - a user account has access to the database that houses all the tables for my django application.

It does *not* have access to the `master` database on the SQL Server and any request for an account that *does* have that level of access would likely be denied. It can create tables in the existing database, but cannot create entirely new databases.

When I run the tests for the application I get the error:

`Got an error creating the test database: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. (262) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

So what is the best course of action for this? Is there a way to manually create the 'test database' and have Django use that for testing purposes so it isn't trying to create a new database when running tests?

Comment: Thats interesting.  Perhaps a bug?  It's not like they explicitly support sql-server.  You could create a ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/, or bring it up in discussion: https://github.com/django.

Comment: Yeah, we use the library `django-pyodbc-azure` that handles the database connection part, so I wasn't sure if maybe *that* was the issue or if there was a way around it. Thanks for links, I'll keep investigating to see what kind of solution I might be able to find.

Comment: I would create a separate settings.py file for tests. Alternatively you can use the decorator `@override_settings`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up having to specify a different database (a local SQLite instance) for testing specifically because the MS-SQL Server instance was locked down on a per user basis and the user rights for django were not going to be allowed to change.

It required additional setup and changing of process' in order to accommodate using local SQLite, but hey, testing works!